# Prove that smallest $\sigma$-field of subsets of $A$ containing the open sets in $A$ is $\{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \mid B \subseteq A\}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, sigma-algebra

Let $A$ be a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$. Then show that the smallest $\sigma$-field of subsets of $A$ containing the open sets in $A$ is $\{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \mid B \subseteq A\}$.

I am thinking to use of good sets principle on the set $G = \{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \mid B \subseteq A\}.$ and $B$ is borel sigma field on $\mathbb{R}$ that means it is the smallest sigma field containing the sets belong to the real line and $B$ is such that it contains in a collection of open intervals that is $A$, but not able to express the proof exactly.It seems so obvious statement but I don't get idea how to write the proof.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If not, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Isn't that almost by definition?

Comment: To be clearer, I think what you want to prove is that $\sigma(\mathscr{A})= \{B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}):  B \subset A\} = \mathscr{A} \cap \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathscr{A} = \{O \subset A: O \text{ is open}.\}$.  And the sample space should be set to be $A$.