# Prove that smallest $\sigma$-field of subsets of $A$ containing the open sets in $A$ is $\{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \mid B \subseteq A\}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, sigma-algebra

Let $A$ be a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$. Then show that the smallest $\sigma$-field of subsets of $A$ containing the open sets in $A$ is $\{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \mid B \subseteq A\}$.

I am thinking to use of good sets principle on the set $G = \{B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \mid B \subseteq A\}.$ and $B$ is borel sigma field on $\mathbb{R}$ that means it is the smallest sigma field containing the sets belong to the real line and $B$ is such that it contains in a collection of open intervals that is $A$, but not able to express the proof exactly.It seems so obvious statement but I don't get idea how to write the proof.

Comment: Please do not simply delete and repost [a closed question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/601636/1352). Instead, if a question is closed, please engage with close voters in the comments, and edit your question to address the reasons given for closure. Such an edit will put your question into a queue where users will vote on reopening.

Comment: How to write the proof? Start from showing whether it is a sigma algebra. Then show if there exists another sigma algebra of same property, the latter is a subclass of the former.